# How to set the background color for individual PlotItem in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I want to to set different background colors for a sequence of subplots, which are PlotItem objects, in a GraphicsLayoutWidget, like this:

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg

win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
win.resize(1200,600)
win.setBackground('w')

color_list = [(r1,g1,b1), (r2,g2,b2), ...]
for j in range(10):
    p = win.addPlot(title="Ch #"+str(j))
    p.plot(y=Y_mean, pen=(0,0,0))
    p.setBackgroundColor(color_list[j]) # <---  Or something similar to that
```

This raises:

```
AttributeError: 'PlotItem' object has no attribute 'setBackgroundColor'
```

I can’t find how to set this property in the class `pyqtgraph.PlotItem` or any of it’s inherited classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the color in the ViewBox of the PlotItem with the [`setBackgroundColor()`](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/viewbox.html#pyqtgraph.ViewBox.setBackgroundColor) method:

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
    win.resize(1200, 600)
    win.setBackground("w")

    color_list = [(100, 10, 34), (20, 30, 40), (40, 146, 10)]
    for j, color in zip(range(3), color_list):
        p = win.addPlot(title="Ch #{}".format(j))
        p.plot(y=np.random.rand(200), pen=(0, 0, 0))
        vb = p.getViewBox()
        vb.setBackgroundColor(color)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]